# Average distance to points in cube with offset

Tags: calculus, geometry

Closed expressions are known for the [average distance of points in a (unit) cube from a corner and from its center](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/CubePointPicking.html):
$$
\begin{align}
\bar{d}_{\text{corner}}
&= \int_0^1 \int_0^1 \int_0^1 \sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2} \,\mathrm{d}x \,\mathrm{d}y \,\mathrm{d}z
\\
&\quad= \frac{\sqrt{3}}{4} - \frac{\pi}{24} - \frac{1}{2} \ln(2) + \ln(1 + \sqrt{3})
\\
\bar{d}_{\text{center}}
&= \int_{-\frac{1}{2}}^{\frac{1}{2}} \int_{-\frac{1}{2}}^{\frac{1}{2}} \int_{-\frac{1}{2}}^{\frac{1}{2}} \sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2} \,\mathrm{d}x \,\mathrm{d}y \,\mathrm{d}z
= \frac{1}{2} \bar{d}_{\text{corner}}
\end{align}
$$

I was wondering if there is a similar expression for the distance from an arbitrary point $\vec{p} = (p_x, p_y, p_z)$, potentially outside the cube:
$$
\bar{d}_{\vec{p}}
= \int_0^1 \int_0^1 \int_0^1 \sqrt{(x - p_x)^2 + (y - p_y)^2 + (z - p_z)^2} \,\mathrm{d}x \,\mathrm{d}y \,\mathrm{d}z
= {?}
$$

Am I missing some simple substitution that can be done, or is this an open question?

Comment: Probably this can be done in closed form, but even the corresponding answer for a unit square is really unpleasant!